# How do I configure my computer to push to GitHub?

Tags: git

I'm using a kit to learn about Raspberry Pi. The kit had a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/sunfounder/davinci-kit-for-raspberry-pi) with code to learn from. I [forked](https://github.com/chivalry/raspberry-pi-ed) their repository on my GitHub account, cloned it to the Raspberry Pi, and am working with my fork. I also set my username and email with `git config`. I'm able to use Git locally to commit changes, but I haven't been able to push my changes back to my fork.

I've set my user ID and email, and the remote is set correctly, confirmed by the `git remote --verbose` command. But when I try to push either the main branch or a new branch with `git push --set-upstream origin <<branch-name>>` the shell just hangs. I've given it plenty of time (>20 minutes) to complete, but nothing happens. The only way I get out is to press Ctrl-C.

How can I push my local changes to my GitHub account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question may be "off topic" for RPi SE, but I've had to address this recently also - here's what I learned:

Effective August, 2021, [GitHub requires *token-based authentication* for `git` operations on repos](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) - userid & passwords are no longer allowed. This article outlines [how to create a personal access token, and use it from the command line](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) w/ `git`